# Java Graphic2D, scaled shape and mouse

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, mouseevent, paint

Hi everybody I have a piece of code that can zoom some shapes into a restricted area but when zooming I can't click the shapes, what can I do for? I can clicked in the old area in the original location.

The code:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseWheelEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseWheelListener;
import java.awt.geom.AffineTransform;
import java.awt.geom.NoninvertibleTransformException;
import java.awt.geom.Point2D;
import java.awt.geom.Rectangle2D;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class ZoomDemo extends JPanel implements Runnable {

AffineTransform tx = new AffineTransform();
Rectangle2D.Double rect1 = new Rectangle2D.Double(100, 100, 30, 60);
Rectangle2D.Double rect2 = new Rectangle2D.Double(150, 250, 60, 40);

public ZoomDemo() {
    this.addMouseWheelListener(new ZoomHandler());
}

@Override
public void paint(Graphics g) {
    super.paint(g);
    Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;

    g2.drawRect(100, 100, 100, 100);
    g2.setClip(100, 100, 100, 100);
    g2.setColor(Color.RED);
    g2.draw(tx.createTransformedShape(rect1));
    g2.setColor(Color.BLUE);
    g2.draw(tx.createTransformedShape(rect2));
}

private class ZoomHandler implements MouseWheelListener, MouseListener {

    double scale = 1.0;

    public ZoomHandler() {
        addMouseListener(this);
    }



    public void mouseWheelMoved(MouseWheelEvent e) {
        if (e.getScrollType() == MouseWheelEvent.WHEEL_UNIT_SCROLL) {

            Point2D p1 = e.getPoint();
            Point2D p2 = null;
            try {
                p2 = tx.inverseTransform(p1, null);
            } catch (NoninvertibleTransformException ex) {

                ex.printStackTrace();
                return;
            }

            scale -= (0.1 * e.getWheelRotation());
            scale = Math.max(0.1, scale);

            tx.setToIdentity();
            tx.translate(p1.getX(), p1.getY());
            tx.scale(scale, scale);
            tx.translate(-p2.getX(), -p2.getY());

            ZoomDemo.this.revalidate();
            ZoomDemo.this.repaint();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent me) {
        System.err.println("click");
        if(rect1.contains(me.getPoint())){
            System.err.println("asdasdsd");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent me) {

    }

    @Override
    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent me) {

    }

    @Override
    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent me) {

    }

    @Override
    public void mouseExited(MouseEvent me) {
    }
}

public void run() {
    JFrame f = new JFrame("Zoom Demo");
    f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    f.getContentPane().add(this);
    f.setSize(600, 600);
    f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    f.setVisible(true);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new ZoomDemo());
}
}
```

Comment: Tou need to "zoom" the mouse position too.

Comment: thanks a lot, that make me thing about transformations then i look for it over the web and i found the solution, i will change the code for if it can be useful to someone.

Comment: I found the solution:

       AffineTransform reverse;
        try {
             reverse = tx.createInverse();

             Point2D mousePositionUC = new Point();

            reverse.transform( new Point( me.getX(), me.getY() ), mousePositionUC );

            if (rect1.contains(mousePositionUC)) {
                System.err.println("nueva " + scale);
            }

        } catch (NoninvertibleTransformException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(ZoomDemo.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }

Comment: @DaironDominguezVega, please add your own answer if you have found it so other people in the future can find the answer faster.